# how to convert mongoose js model to object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am working with node.js and mongoosejs framwork for mongodb. I am trying to convert a mongoose model to an object, I was able to do that, but am getting only fewer elements rather than getting all. Below code which I tried.

**user.js**

```
var schema = new Schema({
name:{ type:string  },

title:{ type:string, default:"mr"  }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', schema);
```

**usermanager.js**

```
var User = require(../user.js);

var user = new User();
console.log(user.toString());
//printed as {_id:2583457assda312, title:'mr'}
```

i am expecting name key in that object. i have also tryed toObject it also giveing me the same response.
ther is any posiblty to achive this?

Comment: `name` is not in the object because you have never set it. Also, I do not understand why `title` is "user" and not mr.

Comment: @Amberlamps this is just a sample data, i have edited that.

Comment: I want to get all elements which i defined in the schema like name and title.

Answer (score 3):

Your usage is intended to be like this:

```
var user = new User({ name: "Fred" })
```

and you will get the values from what you have defined, so in this case:

```
//printed as {_id:2583457assda312, name: "Fred", title:'mr'}
```

Or you supply your title as here:

```
var user = new User({ name: "Wilma", title: "Ms" })
```

and again get your output

```
//printed as {_id:2583457assda312, name: "Wilma", title: "Ms"}
```

If what you are trying to do is **inspect** the schema there is a `paths` property on Mongoose schema objects

```
console.log( user.schema.paths )
```

And that should give you a definition of the various parts of the schema you defined.

Comment: I am trying to inspect paths of schema, I tried user.paths it returning me "undefined".

Comment: My bad, I forgot it was being called from a model. See the edit where we access the `schema` property first